# \nolinebreak inside a figure caption

Tags: captions

I have a centered figure caption. Here's an example of my code:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics [width=\textwidth]{photo}
\caption{ This is my caption. I want the following two words: "TeX LaTeX" to be in the same line. }
\label{fig:2_2_0}
\end{figure}
```

I want the words "TeX" and "LaTeX to be in the same line, always. However, if I type:

```
"TeX \nolinebreak LaTeX"
```

as I always do, it returns me an error («Paragraph ended before caption was complete»).

How can I manage to do that?

Answer (score 3):

One can protect the `\nolinebreak`, as in ``` ``\TeX{} \protect\nolinebreak\LaTeX'' ```.  However, here is another way:

By placing unbreakable text in an `\mbox{}`, a linebreak cannot occur within the text.  A box is an unbreakable entity to both line breaks as well as page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=5.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
FIXED VERSION
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics [width=\textwidth]{photo}
\caption{ This is my caption. I want the following two words: ``\mbox{\TeX{} \LaTeX}'' to be in the same line. }
\label{fig:2_2_0}
\end{figure}

ORIGINAL VERSION
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics [width=\textwidth]{photo}
\caption{ This is my caption. I want the following two words: ``\TeX{} \LaTeX'' to be in the same line. }
\label{fig:2_2_0}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Which is the difference between \mbox and \newline before the first of the 2 unbreakable words?

Comment: @Trial4life If you insert `\newline`, a break will **always** occur at that point.  The use of `\mbox{}`, by contrast, would automatically adjust if you edited your caption text.  Note I edited my answer to also show how to use `\nolinebreak`.